# Typing keys and values in a dictionary to co-vary

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

This is probably a simple issue, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

I have a dictionary that holds values of different type. I want to type the dictionary in a manner such that typescript knows the type of value based on type of the key.

Here is the setup:

```js
type Id = string;

interface Shop {
  id: Id;
  a: ... // `a` is a property unique to Shop
}

interface ShopOwner {
  id: Id;
  b: ... // `b` is a property unique to ShopOwner
}

type Objects = {[key: Id]: Shop | ShopOwner }

// when I call the dictionary with a key that is guaranteed to return ShopOwner,
// typescript throws an error saying returned value can be either object ShopOwner or Shop
// and Shop doesn't have property b 
const shopOwner = dictionary[key].b
```

I can check the type of value before I access `b`, but I feel like there is an elegant solution using generics. Something along the lines of

```js
type Id<T is either Shop or ShopOwner> = ?
type Objects<T is either Shop or ShopOwner> = {[key: Id<T>]: T}
```

How would I implement something like this?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you flesh the pseudocode out into a true [mre] that shows what you're talking about when pasted into an IDE?  Especially how you intend to initialize such a dictionary... how does the compiler (or a human being, for that matter) know which keys are associated with which values?

Comment: Looking at this more, I think we really need you to explain what you mean by "the type of the key", given that keys are something wide like `string` in the absence of other information.  Maybe `A` ids start with `"a"` and `B` ids start with `"b"`?  If so [you can do this](https://tsplay.dev/w2z2Yw).  Maybe `A` ids and `B` ids are completely arbitrary at compile time and you can only know at runtime which is which, and so the best you could do is some nominal-like typing for them? If so [you can do this](https://tsplay.dev/NB58pw).  Or maybe there's some other rule... help

Comment: Hi @jcalz. Thank you for the taking the time to write a thoughtful response. I wasn't very clear with my use case. Please see this [code box](https://tsplay.dev/ND2d8W).

Comment: @jcalz Basically, I have a tree data structure, where every level of the tree holds nodes of type that is different from other levels. I normalized this tree into a dictionary for O(1) look up time, and now struggling to type this dictionary. I thought to type the 'id' property of each node in a manner that co-varies with with node type.  All ids are just generic UUID strings, though. I may have adopted a wrong data structure for this.

Comment: When you say "generic UUID strings" I assume you mean that you have no idea at compile time which ones correspond to which types.  If so then the best you can do is to make a [nominal-like type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) like [shown here](https://tsplay.dev/N7oqGN) (which is the same as I showed you above except based off this new example).  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, this works. I did not know about nominal aliasing. I think you can copy/paste your comment as the response, and I'll mark it as resolved. Thank you!

Comment: I will write up an answer when an explanation when I get a chance

Comment: While I'm writing this up, would you mind [edit]ing your example code to be the `Shop`/`ShopOwner` pair instead of the `ObjectA`/`ObjectB` version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you knew at compile time how to identify which `id`s correspond to `Shop`s and which ones correspond to `ShopOwner`s, then things would be easier.  For example, if the situation where `Shop` ids began with the string `"shop_"` and `ShopOwner` ids began with the string `"owner_"`, then you could use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to keep track of this distinction:

```
type ShopId = `shop_${string}`;
type ShopOwnerId = `owner_${string}`;

interface ShopOwner {
  id: ShopOwnerId;
  name: string;
  shop: Shop;
}

interface Shop {
  id: ShopId;
  name: string;
  address: string;
}
```

Then the `dataNormalized` table would be [an intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of [`Record` object types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) which match up `ShopId` keys to `Shop` values, and `ShopOwnerId` keys to `ShopOwner` values:

```
declare const dataNomalized: Record<ShopId, Shop> & Record<ShopOwnerId, ShopOwner>;
```

And your `getEntity()` could be easily written as

```
function getEntity<I extends ShopId | ShopOwnerId>(id: I) {
  const ret = dataNomalized[id];
  if (!ret) throw new Error("no entry at '" + id + "'")
  return ret;
}
```

And you'd get runtime and compile time behavior that works:

```
console.log(getEntity("shop_b").address.toUpperCase());
console.log(getEntity("owner_a").shop.address.toUpperCase());
getEntity("who knows") // compiler error, 
// 'string' is not assingbale to '`shop_${string}` | `owner_${string}`'
```

Unfortunately, you have no idea which `ids` correspond to `Shop`s and which ones correspond to `ShopOwner`s... or at least the compiler has no idea.  They are both `string`s and the compiler can't easily distinguish them.

---

In this case, the best you can do is to *pretend* that there's some such distinction.  One technique that's used in this case is to ["brand" a primitive type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) like `string` with a tag that says what it's used for:

```
type Id<K extends string> = string & { __type: K }
type ShopId = Id<"Shop">;
type ShopOwnerId = Id<"ShopOwner">;
```

So here a `ShopId` is, supposedly, a `string` which also has a `__type` property of [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"Shop"`.  And a `ShopOwnerId` is similar except its `__type` property is `"ShopOwner"`.  If that were really true, you could just inspect the `__type` property and behave accordingly.  But of course, at runtime, you just have `string`s and you can't add properties to them.  No, this is just a convenient lie we're telling to the compiler.

You have similar interface definitions,

```
interface ShopOwner {
  id: ShopOwnerId;
  name: string;
  shop: Shop;
}

interface Shop {
  id: ShopId;
  name: string;
  address: string;
}
```

And your `dataNormalized` is still of type `Record<ShopId, Shop> & Record<ShopOwnerId, ShopOwner>`, but now you have to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that your `id`s are of the appropriate type, since the compiler cannot verify it:

```
const owner = {
  id: "a",
  name: "Peter",
  shop: {
    id: "b",
    name: "Peters's Shop",
    address: "123 Main St"
  }
} as ShopOwner; // assert

const dataNomalized = {
  a: owner,
  b: owner.shop,
} as Record<ShopId, Shop> & Record<ShopOwnerId, ShopOwner>; // assert
```

And although `getEntity()` can be implemented the same way, you'll find it hard to use directly:

```
getEntity("a") // compiler error!
getEntity("b") // compiler error!
//Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ShopId | ShopOwnerId'.
```

You could just go ahead and keep asserting those keys are of the right type, but you run the risk of asserting the wrong thing:

```
getEntity("a" as ShopId).address.toUpperCase(); // okay for the compiler, but
// runtime error:  getEntity(...).address is undefined
```

In order to try to claw some safety back, you could write some functions that do runtime validation of your keys before promoting them to `ShopId` or `ShopOwnerId`.  Say a general [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) along with some helpers for each specific id type:

```
function isValidId<K extends string>(x: string, type: K): x is Id<K> {
  // do any runtime validation you want to do here, if you care
  if (!(x in dataNomalized)) return false;
  const checkKey: string | undefined = ({ Shop: "address", ShopOwner: "shop" } as any)[type];
  if (!checkKey) return false;
  if (!(checkKey in (dataNomalized as any)[x])) return false;
  return true;
}

function shopId(x: string): ShopId {
  if (!isValidId(x, "Shop")) throw new Error("Invalid shop id '" + x + "'");
  return x
}

function shopOwnerId(x: string): ShopOwnerId {
  if (!isValidId(x, "ShopOwner")) throw new Error("Invalid shop id '" + x + "'");
  return x;
}
```

Now you can safely write your code:

```
console.log(getEntity(shopId("b")).address.toUpperCase());
console.log(getEntity(shopOwnerId("a")).shop.address.toUpperCase());
```

Well, you'll still get runtime errors when you make a mistake, but at least they will be caught as early as possible:

```
getEntity(shopId("who knows")).address.toUpperCase(); // Invalid shop id 'who knows'
```

Honestly, it's not *great*.  Ideally you'd refactor so your ids could be told apart at compile time.  But in the absence of that, you could at least use branded primitives to help you keep things straight, even though they are less of a guarantee since there is no such distinction at runtime.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBhA9mGBLANhAKlpEgN4CwAUEkgC4CeMyAygBZowCSAJkgLxIADKGxgB9ACQkoNAE5ZgAcwC+AgNyVq9RklbsA8gHdgEGdz6C0RkxKmz5ytZQ1J5NEwDMEzEYeMzSztRYXABcOj5WplzqVNRIoJBh0nKKMXFIwuxhujBpSEpOsa4eXuHsAbFBoWWc0YHx4BBJdqn1IFxcMtBQzSkKeQUUzvBowNJIln7ZEX7m5JUu1QBEk9YgSwA09QlNSEsAChBuMpv1mTBh8+lVYUvnogBGpwvUO7eHx1AA5FA1z9dIdqdbq3ACMACYAMxIACyIHkOhoS3qg2oShiw1G4y4IBoIAAchgQDgsAAvCDVABKEBGMi4AB4ctwNjUAHxIABkSGptIZOV8JmZNQFMnZ-CucVWMlEIDCUq2C3uDzlkQAdOcFWiMbF3ABXYDwGhYUZIBRHACiwCN9HpHCQEAAHm5gFxfkyeAAfYWRbisgAUwTCHAAlBV0iMxjQkF0o-wcXjCWBiWSKQBtYIAXTyQXcSD9AEIY6GaCwZJZ4hADEhzTIyzI-UtgGh7VaZHRAVGvkskABqRa9vZd4P1GO6mTAaNHAbOWTtiXUCNQNB4VU4NAKP1mmiW610BtKpbB1VArpQKCqmhoACqMEYMhQICgED9weD2aQi+XEFX683FqtWD0A2Uoyoe6oiMeHSnuel43neD5Pi+b71FuO6AXuSwGGwSAANZNgYUCHkgAD0xH2rWaAyCyPwtAoXwuL8TZRo+UD2A8xLIJeSBfEIIg2Mk9gqEgXoCCBkgCYoKhfM4Sgfri8AsHmEChvOH5Yl+P4bspMmFIMlA7LApSJvIxIVDODDINw9IANL2k6EAur8EkKGKGS0ZypBIKIohaLstmorQFk1GY-BWUsORLKyeS+d6fghUgYX8pEkXakEVolIgsUmGGcSBllUTvm8bl9O+5zTOw05DEU6UyJ4mU5DlNzBXUCxFc574niCxX2JVmKRhMkRzPUeVLOsmpxEVBxHCY-xxGVjW5csTzjekk0fCY3xuiIs3pJ1Z5glCsLwhOTBIiiMmAlt+iRKlan9fGBJEiS5I8OKbQqn4K1IMqA1+OB7DjbJj7cjSlF8iIQo5OyXI8mDjIzIKXAsklfhRYUzh6gaRomqhAE2najrOq6zXCflvoBtUIYLYuUYxuYD2JsmL3plwWbDbmBZFrQpblsYVY1nWDZNi2s4dtx3Z9sEA5LEOI5HGOE4xr1Or6oaxoTlgUAAGrJlwVm2YTDnE85-oOr09gsr5YTWcGYQOgxCUMtZ7KqaRSBcM2IDAO2Mj6kaxAAG667i6tIHQaC6kgBhe1GXEe0gLAmBALJYLm4eR-AIBdOzeb5n69sIgzT0plwr6TjQCtIJ4OBPu+NMfon8A4dZEB0Obiik-qXAQO48gUuYfokDUtx7YRyMIzItznN2QO-F7dDBqmvlswsqe5wpNLN63oajuOVfErXOcFn6G9Ny37YIn6RdJs9-fA-Pi8OhmZe7xO1eHwsr+0L7EDK9QmNqxNOcbg+d24KFtiTVSa8Cyax1iSPWXB84snCttMuJYyxVj5tWCi9YlgcGAEHeBGQRD9i7AOe2fYZaHnfF-B0Okqr-1VtjCc5wRQgLNt1RQECUaIwWtA-MsDdbsOQTwk4aCeaYMrNgwWeCCG62IeUKWZC+wUMHNQuWFc94Oj-qaf8u4GzrFDG7EYmBcDZRMHWfMzhcb6KWE8IxZETHYDwP4CxlErGxFIgAQRkAoXUkArQTFzDFGifR6Ka3iGgZiZ4sAKFAA8PAtBmxwBkI0Y4QTAraC+O6UmojuBfFVIUTQbYFooT0ehAx3ZgbuiPKPC815bwmAQs+N8JEyJoBwiAOg9Q3a+wAsQNxk8kCAF4NwApTu6O3HjPcqoZm1Kgt0B2Xce59x4EUuINiKl2KqVdGAbDS7-RgJBYEZ4LqZxoApJSKl6ifhXGuLSw5Yh6ViDc78dy-yTP0cAxBWzXxHOgvUuCTTHwtOQs89StzfwbKAqwn03zDFHnOH87oALGn3mBUhW6UKMJYWbHhSwhEHHkTrCyHxfiAlRjQMEoKoT7DhMYlEy6rE4kgASZxZJWc0nZUpZk5A2SIaejJlwAp1jynQv5Q2HFuF8IErmccmCDT4LotaW7fBhCpbnFIZKvFBF6LowoEoIAA)